# how to copy latex codes without extra spaces?

Tags: editors

Typing latex codes I often use frequent line changes. When I copy, for example, the abstract of a paper from the latex codes, and paste it to some place, for example, a paper submission system, the text appears ugly because of a lot of line changes (maybe with some extra spaces too). Is there a direct command or way to operate in Latex so that the text I copy has no line changes or extra spaces? I am using TeXLive 2014. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this about the end product PDF or how it looks in the editor?

Comment: do you mean copy from the latex source (in which case it's a feature of the editor) or copy from the pdf as plain text in which case in general the answer is no

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I mean copy from the latex source. It is a feature of the editor. I am using TeXShop 3.48.1.

Comment: @percusse  Sorry for the confusion. I mean copy from the Latex source from TeXShop.

Comment: Sounds like it could be an end-of-line mismatch between your latex editor and your browser of choice - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline - what's the operating system?